# Find angles in a diagram.

Tags: geometry

How to solve this? I think use umbrella theorum.........
[image]

Comment: At least, you can rotate your picture $90^0$ to make it readily readable.

Comment: @Mick I fix it~

Comment: I think I should draw a foot of prependicular AB and AC from M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Initial deductions:-

(1):- $\angle BAC = 90^0$.

(2):- $\angle MBC = \angle MCB = \angle BAM = = \angle MAC = 45^0$.

(3):- (1) & (2) imply KLNA is a square.

Next, express separately the ratios $\dfrac {CL}{LB}$ and $\dfrac {CN}{NA}$ in terms of x.

Then, equating the two ratios, we have $\dfrac {135 + 0.5x^2}{60} = \dfrac {0.5x^2}{60 - 0.5x^2}$. From which, we get the value of $x^2$. Result follows.

Comment: I got S (AKL)= 45

Comment: @user366725 Good and don't forget to tick it as a correct answer. But in this question, I don't see the purpose of $S_{AKM} = S_{AMN} = 120$.